# How to bring back objects?

Tags: objects

I pressed unlink on a torus and it's gone. I've tried searching online but nothing has worked. any way to recover it? I'm pretty new to blender and this is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

control+z = undo a number of times etc/menu = redo also.
alt+h to reveal hidden if hidden.